# Java: Evaluate if in a group of setting variables, a variable already had the same value

Tags: java, optimization

I'm currently trying to optimize my Code and I have something like this:

```
contact.name = updatedContact.name;
contact.forname = updatedContact.forname;
contact.email = updatedContact.email;
contact.save();
```

contact.save() checks if any changes have been made already, but it's rather slow as it goes through the Database to check.

So I thought, that I could implement a check, if a value actually has been updated at all, kinda like this:

```
if(contact.name != updatedContact.name || contact.forname != updatedContact.forname || contact.email != updatedContact.email){
    contact.name = updatedContact.name;
    contact.forname = updatedContact.forname;
    contact.email = updatedContact.email;
    contact.save();
}
```

This would make it so save only gets called if needed, but in my actual code, I am not just setting 3 fields, I'm setting close to 100, which would make a giant and ugly if.
Or I could make an if in front of each setting and an else which sets a flag or something like that.

Is there another, faster way to do this check?

Comment: If fields have always same names, maybe you can use reflection or just convert these objects to Map<String, Object> and then compare them.

Comment: ohh, this sounds smart, I will try this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the better way is to deal with local variables for the lifetime of the program, and only deal with the database at the end of the program.

Comment: This is the end of the program. At least the end of this snippet. I have to save here and put it into the DB, as else I would run into memory issues